# Order by with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, distinct

Firstly my sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CarTable.CarPlate), CarTable.CarImage, EventTable.FirstDate
FROM CarTable JOIN EventTable ON CarTable.CarId = EventTable.CarId
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

I am trying order rows by date and that works fine but I want all plates to be written only one time. I mean I need to see all car's last event but it seems I am using distinct wrong. What is the best way of doing this ?

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, its a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. I.e. `SELECT DISTINCT(CarTable.CarPlate), CarTable.CarImage,...` is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT CarTable.CarPlate, CarTable.CarImage...`, which is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT CarTable.CarPlate , (CarTable.CarImage)...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    c.CarPlate, 
    c.CarImage, 
    FirstDate = MAX(e.FirstDate)
FROM CarTable c
INNER JOIN EventTable e
    ON c.CarId = e.CarId
GROUP BY c.CarPlate, c.CarImage
ORDER BY MAX(e.FirstDate) DESC
```

Note:

- Use meaningful alias to improve readability.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks! Updated.

Comment: I replaced 'c' with 'e' for MAX functions and it did the trick. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

see,if this work without using aggregate function.

```
SELECT c.CarPlate
    ,c.CarImage
    ,ev.FirstDate
FROM CarTable C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT max(FirstDate) FirstDate
    FROM EventTable E
    WHERE c.CarId = e.CarId
    ) ev
ORDER BY ev.FirstDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with a window and `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  C.CarId,
  C.CarImage, 
  MAX(E.FirstDate) OVER (PARTITION BY E.CarId) FirstDate
FROM CarTable C
JOIN EventTable E ON C.CarId = E.CarId
ORDER BY FirstDate DESC
```